# How can I use window.scrollby with react?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to click a button which scrolls down to a specific portion of my app. So currently I have:

```
class Nav extends Component {
  foo(){
    console.log('baz')
    window.scrollTo(0, 100);
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <nav>
          <a href="#" onClick={()=> this.foo()}>About</a>

        </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

This will console.log "baz" but won't scroll down to 100

Comment: try this, assign a `id` to that element then use `document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView();`

Comment: nope that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Remove the

```
href="#"
```

This is causing the link to link the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this -

```js
const handleRef = (param) => window.scrollTo(0, param);
<p onClick={()=> handleRef(1000)} >Drops</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import react from "react";


const Stchange = ()=>{


const dev = ()=>{

window.scrollBy(0,50);

}
    return(

        <>

        <button onClick={dev}>Scroll</button>

          <h1>There are man struc Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The</h1>

        </>
    )
}

export default Stchange;
```

Comment: This answer could use an explanation

Answer (score 0):

**We have to prevent the default action of the anchor tag using event.preventDefault() method and change href="#" to href="/" in anchor tag**

```
class Nav extends Component {

    foo(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       console.log('baz')
       window.scrollTo(0, 100);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <nav>
              <a href="/" onClick={(event)=> this.foo(event)}>About</a>
            </nav>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this quick example for your desired result:

```
import React from 'react';

function ScrollExample() {
  const handleScrollButtonClick = () => {
    // Scroll down by 100 pixels vertically
    window.scrollBy(0, 100);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleScrollButtonClick}>Scroll Down</button>
      <div style={{ height: '1000px' }}>
        {/* Content to create a scrollable area */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ScrollExample;
```